# Jackson Deserialization of List with Default Typing

Tags: java, json, list, jackson, abstract-class

Good Day,
Hi All,

I'm trying to configure the Jackson Object Mapper to de-serialize any json String to my domain specific objects.
I've configured the Object Mapper as below

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
mapper.enableDefaultTypingAsProperty(DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, "remoteClass");
```

In my domain, any json string should contain a remoteClass property which denotes the actual JAVA POJO (canonical name) that it corresponds to. The above configuration helps resolve abstract types

However with the above, now java.util.Lists are not getting properly deserialized, since they are abstract types.

I get the following error
Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected VALUE_STRING: need JSON String that contains type id (for subtype of java.util.List)

Object Mapper in this case is not resorting to the default collectionFallBacks

I tried other configuration to overcome the issue such as

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("test", Version.unknownVersion());
module.addAbstractTypeMapping(List.class, ArrayList.class);
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

However these lead to other problems.

Can someone please help me with the same. I've spent days on this now. This seems like a limitation in Jackson. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem recently. Try this, in your POJO, instead of defining property as

```
List<SimpleModule>
```

define it as

```
List<Object>.
```